# EF Code First Model definition for one to one mapping with cascade delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have a member model with an address in a one to one style where an address row can only belong to one member.  I'm trying to figure out how to define this so Member owns Address and Address is cascade deleted when I delete a Member.

```
public class Member
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Address")]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

I also have address

```
public class Address : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

I've tried the following to get the address to cascade delete

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Member>()
        .HasRequired(m => m.Address)
        .WithRequiredDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

And

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Member>()
        .HasRequired(m => m.Address)
        .WithRequiredPrinciple()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

Can someone help here put me on the right track?  The migraions fail with the following line.

```
System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One 
or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid 
in Role 'Member_Address_Source' in relationship 'Member_Address'. Because the
Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the 
multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
```

---

Found this from the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx) - one to one with only one navigation property

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<OfficeAssignment>()
    .HasKey(t => t.InstructorID);

 modelBuilder.Entity<Instructor>()
     .HasRequired(t => t.OfficeAssignment)
     .WithRequiredPrincipal();
```

I'll post up if it works when I get a chance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few different things but this is the way EF creates a one-to-one mapping with only a navigation on one side of the relationship..

```
public class Member
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int MemberId {get;set;}
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Address>()
        .HasKey(t => t.MemberID);

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Member>()
        .HasRequired(t => t.Address)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal();
}
```

Doing this makes the cascade delete work properly so the address is deleted when the member is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is twisted upside down. What you've written now is that each member has an address, which results in a fact that one address can be present for several members, meaning that in hierarchy table, address is above the member. Deleting a child can't result in deleting a parent.

Try deleting the address and your member(s) will be gone, if you want to test what I just wrote.

For your logic to work, you need to write:

```
public class Member
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
...
}

public class Address : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int MemberId {get;set;}
    public virtual Member Member {get;set;}
    ....
}
```

If you turn on cascade delete, and delete member, address will be deleted as well.

EDIT:

If you're looking for 1 to 1 relationship, it goes like this:

```
public class Member
{
[Key]
public int Id {get;set;}

...

public virtual Address Address {get;set;}
}

public class Address
{
[ForeignKey("Member")]
public int Id {get;set;}

...

public virtual Member Member {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Would that not create a many to one relationship?  There could be many address entities to one member?  I see how I've made a mistake as well though in that I should probably state that an address can only have one member

Comment: Well if address can have only 1 member, then you have 1 to 1 relationship. I've pasted a code for that as well now.